# Two columns divs, ordered vertically

Tags: html, css, multiple-columns

I need a 2 columns HTML-CSS layout using divs. 
From 0 to 5 elements, it should have only one column. From 6 to 10, two columns. 
And maximun of 6 elements per column.

- 0 to 5:

```
elem1
elem2
elem3
elem4
elem5
```

- 6 to 10

```
elem1   elem7
elem2   elem8
elem3   elem9
elem4   elem10
elem5
elem6
```

Comment: Your elements will be of fixed height or will have variable height?

Comment: Similar question was asked not so long ago... impossible (with just CSS), with variable heights... JS could be the solution.

Comment: [**This**](https://jsfiddle.net/j7gxf6kh/) is the only variant that I can offer you.

Comment: @sinisake check my answer

Comment: @ArtemLopatiy, if heights are fixed, then it is easy.... but: https://jsfiddle.net/8b3b9x44/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In that case we can use **CSS3** transformation to achieve needed behaviour.

```css
.container {
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    border: 1px dotted black;
    padding:0;
    transform: rotate(270deg);
}

.card {
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  float: right;
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: inline-block;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  transform: rotate(90deg)
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="card">1</div>
  <div class="card">2</div>
  <div class="card">3</div>
  <div class="card">4</div>
  <div class="card">5</div>
  <div class="card">6</div>
  <div class="card">7</div>
  <div class="card">8</div>
  <div class="card">9</div>
  <div class="card">10</div>
</div>
```

Make sure to **use transparent container div**, because its' content will be rotated.

Comment: Thanks Artem, this code is compatible with IE < 10?